# Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

I am facing the following error in my application.

```
    clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/madhavadudipalli/Desktop/ ios projects/Little Flower Public School /Little Flower Public School Ipad/Little Flower Public S  chool HD-Prefix*.pch'
    clang: error: no input files
    Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1
```

Please tell me what does this mean and what should I do to resolve this one. Been sometime since I have stuck on this one. Kindly Guide me where am I going wrong here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Lots of spaces in strange places in that `.pch` path; that can't be right...

Comment: @trojanfoe please tell me wt to do now

Comment: I've no idea.  The Xcode project is clearly mis-configured.  I'd delete the `.pch` file reference and re-add it, or failing that recreate the project from scratch (saving any source files first).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34209145/how-to-debug-dsymutil-error-clang-modules-are-expected-to-have-exactly-1-compi

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Following steps fixed this problem:

**Issue**: Compiler unable to locate **Little Flower Public S  chool HD-Prefix.pch** file. This is because Location of Prefix Header file **Little Flower Public S  chool HD-Prefix-Prefix.pch** in Project Target is incorrect.

The location is defined in Project Target/Build setting. You will need to go to:
Project Target -> Build Settings Tab -> Scroll down and Look for "Apple LLVM Compiler 5.1 - Language" Underneath this node -> You will find the key/value setting for Prefix Header file.

Normally Prefix header file is located under "Supporting File" Folder in your project

Comment: located Prefix Header file and it is empty. After that what needs to be done?