# Apple LLVM 6.0 Error After Changing Architectures

Tags: ios, xcode, open-source, cpu-architecture, llvm-clang

I have been working on reviving an older open source project, and when I updated the architecture from `$(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT)` to `$(ARCHS_STANDARD)`, Xcode gave me a very long error with the title `Apple LLVM 6.0 Error` which ended with the line `Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1`. I tried undoing the architecture change, but it still gave the error when I ran it again.

The previous build worked perfectly, and the only changes that were made on the erroneous build were:

1) I moved the project to Dropbox

2) I changed the architecture

Here is the full error: http://pastebin.com/huLnWc7v

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to compile ARM code as if it were ARM64. Since it's just an app and not an extension, I don't need to do that. So, under Project>Target>Build Settings> Architectures I changed the Architectures key I standard architectures, and the Valid Architectures key to armv7.

Answer (score 0):

Try This , It may solve your problem.

Issue: Compiler unable to locate `.pch` file. This is because Location of Prefix Header file `.pch` in Project Target is incorrect.

The location is defined in Project Target/Build setting. You will need to go to: Project Target -> Build Settings Tab -> Scroll down and Look for "Apple LLVM Compiler 6.0 - Language" Underneath this node -> You will find the key/value setting for Prefix Header file.

Normally Prefix header file is located under "Supporting File" Folder in your project

Reference : [Anbu.Karthik](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24184503/3859370)

[image]

Comment: So, do I enter the current location of the prefix header (for example /UserName/Dropbox/MyApp/MyApp-Prefix.pch), or do I leave it as MyApp/MyApp-Prefix.pch?

Comment: Actually, I just got another answer from a friend, and his solution worked. I'll post it below.

Comment: I am glad that your problem was solved, and accept your own answer so that it will help others also.

Comment: Ok, I will accept it as soon as I can, it says I have to wait another 15 hours.