# How to debug dsymutil error: "Clang modules are expected to have exactly 1 compile unit."

Tags: ios, xcode, build, dsymutil

Received this error message during GenerateDSYMFile phase for an iOS app:

> /Users/name/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache/HASH/FrameworkName-HASH:
>   Clang modules are expected to have exactly 1 compile unit.
>       Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/dsymutil
>   failed with exit code 1

Comment: Found this diff which includes the error message: http://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/llvm-commits/Week-of-Mon-20150921/301239.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Deleted:

```
~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
```

And was able to build again.